# How do I turn RGB into a 4char hex color string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, hex

I'm trying to turn a RGB value into a 4 char hex color (`FC0C` instead of `FFCC00CC`), how would I do this in python?

I am currently using 6 char hex, but it is too long.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. A 4 char value can represent less values than 8 char one. What should it be when the input is e.g. "FDC10000"? Do you round them or truncate them?

Comment: `8` chars represent `4` integer values from `0-255`. Using `4` chars representation effectively quantized the value to `0-15`. So convert each `2` char into int, then `max(min(round(num/16), 15), 0)`, then convert back to hex (should be single char). Concat everything together and vola!

Answer (score 0):

You can use code to get 4char hex

```
char6_hex = "FFCC00CC"
char4_hex = char6_hex[0]

index = 0
for i in range(1, len(char6_hex)):
    if char6_hex[i] != char6_hex[index]:
        char4_hex += char6_hex[i]
        index = i
        
print(char4_hex)
```

Comment: This will not work with other inputs, like "FFFF0000"

Comment: is there a shorter and faster way to do this? What I'm making requires it to be fast. Also I do not want to make existing hex shorter, I want to turn rgb into 4 char hex

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you had the rgba value (rgb is red green blue, rgba is red green blue alpha/transparency; since you want 4 digits, it's rgba not rgb)

```py
rgba = (255, 204, 0, 0.8)
```

To get an individual value, we need to divide by 16, so that `0` is `0`, `16` is `1`, ..., `255` is `F`

```py
"0123456789ABCDEF"[rgba[0] // 16] # double // is floored division
# outputs '6'
```

Since alpha is on the interval `[0, 1]`, multiply it by 16 and floor it to get it to `[0, 16]`, and compensate for that 16 by adding an extra F to the string.

Putting that together, we get

```py
import math

rgba = (255, 204, 0, 0.8)
def hex4(rgba):
    return "".join("0123456789ABCDEF"[channel_color // 16] for channel_color in rgba[:3]) + "0123456789ABCDEFF"[math.floor(rgba[3] * 16)]

print(hex4(rgba)) # FC0C
```

Comment: I need a faster way of doing this, this takes around 0.2 seconds, it cant take more than 0.065 seconds